# How to measure shoe size (of Dr. Martens boots)?

Tags: shoes

I have a old, broken pair of Dr. Martens boots. (We use them now to grow plants in it).

I want to order the same size again, but the number is gone, the printing is not readable any more.

How should I measure the boots and calculate the size?

I'm mostly interested in european size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply measure the length and width of the insole.

The length will give you the size and the width, naturally, the width fitting letter.

If the insole has rotted through the activities of your plants, measure the inside of the boot.

Conversions from insole measurements to shoe size are found on the web, for example [here](http://www.precisionorthotic.com/forms/shoeChartPOL.pdf).

Failing that, take the insole to any shoe shop.  They should be able to do the conversion to size for you.